# I can't connect to phpmyadmin using php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm obviously new to PHP, and I've been asked by a friend to create a dynamic blog that could use continuously. I wanted it to connect to phpMyAdmin so it would be easier, but when I try to connect with it to my web page, it always fails and my set error appears. I don't know what to look up to help me. I'm sorry if I'm not clear. Post if you want me to go more into detail.

Here's my code:

```
<?php



$dbhost = 'localhost';

$dbuser = ' root';

$dbpass = '';

$dbname = 'blog1';

$connect = mysqli_connect($dbname, $dbuser, $dbhost, $dbpass) or die ('Cannot connect to database.');

echo "Succesfully connected to database!";



?>
```

Comment: Your biggest issue is you don't know the difference between a database server and tools for working with it

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: mysqliconnect only connects to MySql database. PHPMyAdmin is a program that allows to conduct some specific tasks with MySql database. Mainly concerning database administration. Which means creating tables, saving backups loading backups, changing the settings of MySql.

Comment: You don't 'connect` to phpmyadmin neverthless you do connect to a database from your script.

Comment: "to create a dynamic blog that could use continuously." PHP is NOT the language for this, PHP was not designed for asynchronous database connections. I would look into using mongodb and some sort of node.js stack.

Answer (score 0):

Test This

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';

$dbuser = ' root';

$dbpass = '';

$dbname = 'blog1';

$connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die ('Cannot connect to database.');

echo "Succesfully connected to database!";
```

The mysqli_connect() was called in wrong way.

Comment: Test what? That's a bunch of code which looks like the code in the question. Try describing what you changed and why instead of expressing your answer in the form of a game of spot-the-difference.

Comment: The mysqli_connect function was called wrong the variables was in wrong position.

Comment: Does it matter which position they are in? Truthfully, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Yes otherwise PHP tries to find a server with address of your Database Name, and everything gets wrong.

Comment: So, is it weird if an in need teenager asked you for help on his horribly coded website?

Comment: If you need to learn PHP there is a lot of tutorials on the internet you can check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp for some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';

    $dbuser = 'root';

    $dbpass = 'root123';

    $dbname = 'mydb';

    $connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die ('Cannot connect to database.');
```

If you run PHPMyAdmin on localhost uncomment in file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

this line:  **mysqli.allow_local_infile = On**

Restart Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart or   sudo service apache2 restart
```